# Controller values not available to template after $.ajax success in Ember

Tags: ember.js

After much frustration with ember data, I'm trying a simpler approach to fetching & displaying data in Ember. I use $.ajax() to load data in a controller and update the controller's title property. This works. However, the template never updates.  It displays 'Old Value'.

What needs to be done to make the template see the new value?

I'm working with Ember 3.1

```
    // controllers/index.js
    import Controller from '@ember/controller';

    export default Controller.extend({

        title:'Old Value',

        getData: $.ajax(
            {
            type: "GET",
            url:"https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1",
            success: function(data) {
                console.log("success", data);
                this.title = data.title;
                console.log("title: ", this.title); // logs new value: 'sunt aut fac..'
            }
        }
    )
});
```

**template**

```
 // templates/index.hbs
<h1>this is the index route</h1>
<h3>Title is: {{title}}</h3>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am going to present two ways of doing this here for completeness sake, one with ember-data and one without. Firstly without.

Ember Controllers have very little flexibility in terms of lifecycle hooks, especially compared to components. However you can use the init method here to solve this issue. For example you could re-write the above like so:

```
init() {
  this._super(...arguments);

  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1',
    success: data => this.set('title', data.title),
  });
},
```

In this case you have a reference to the correct `this` and your request will be made when the application loads (same as your current implementation).

Now to do this with ember-data instead we just add the following to your route:

```
model() {
  return $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1',
  });
},
```

This will return the result of the ajax request as your controllers model. So then in the controller we just alias the data we are expecting.

```
import { alias } from '@ember/object/computed';

...

title: alias('model.title'),
```

This will automatically be updated to the title once the model resolves.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the setter method. Try `this.set('title', data.title);` instead.

Also, make sure you're using an arrow in your `success` callback (ie. `() => {}`), so that you're bound to the correct object.

Comment: You are correct. 'this' is the problem. I tried using an arrow function as the success handler. But, 'this' is undefined.  

success: (data) => {
      console.log(this); // undefined
 }

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of issues with your code.

1. At the moment your `$.ajax` call runs only once - very early, when Ember initializes controller, or even earlier.
2. `this` inside `success` callback is not `controller`, it's something else. Some of jquery objects or even `window` (don't want to dig into jquery docs to find out what exactly).
3. In Ember we use `model` hook of route to fetch data, because it will be called every time user visits route.

It seems that your issue is not ember data. Your issue is that you didn't read [documentation](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/tutorial/ember-cli/) or didn't try to understand it.

Comment: Thanks for points 1, 2, & 3. They are helpful. Your comment below those points, not so much.